# Mark airflow task with custom status

Tags: airflow

I was trying to create a dag which has only one task. Can I mark the task with required status like skipped or no status?

Requirement: Generally I will be looking at s3 bucket for every one minute and if files available I will do some processing. otherwise, I will just leave. I want to see this visibility in UI. so. I was trying to mark task status as skipped so that.

is this right way to do ? do we have any other way to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to mark a task as skipped, you can raise an `AirflowSkipException`. When raised, the execution of the task will stop and the task will get marked as skipped.

[This example Airflow dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_skip_dag.py#L34) of a `DummySkipOperator` demonstrates an operator which gets marked as skiped by raising the above exception.

Comment: Thanks, @jdimella, What about remaining status like "no_status" and "up_for_reschedule"  ?

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider accepting my answer. As for the _no_status_ and _up_for_reschedule_ states, I've had a quick look but wasn't able to find anything on how to force a task into those states. You may be able to manually set the task state to those by manipulating the _TaskInstance_ object, but I am unsure if this is possible or what effect it would have.